# Inter Thread Pre processer data for mulitple samplers in jmeter

Tags: group-by, jmeter, communication, jmeter-plugins

```
Test Plan
Http Cookie
Http Cache
CSV CONFIG file[having firstname column  with 1000 records]

TG1-1000
Sampler 1
Sampler 2-firstnamefromcsv
Regxfromsampler2Response
InterThreadpostprocesserfromsampler2-{empid}
Sampler 3

TG2-1000
Sampler 1
samepler 2{search firstname present in csv so passing {firstname}
InterThreadpreprocesser-fetching from empid
Sampler 3
InterThreadpreprocesser-fetching from empid[same has to use in sampler 3 also]

TG3-1000
Sampler 1
samepler 2
Sampler 3
```

QUE: on utilizing preprocess in TG2-sampler 2, same variable not able to utilise in sampler 3 as fifo_Sync is now empty on utilising by sampler 2, how can I handle this?

Comment: @Dmitri T can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

1. For me it doesn't look like you need to use 3 Thread Groups at all, just move everything into one Thread Group and you won't need this [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).
2. You can work it around by putting the same value to the [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue in TG2. It can be another queue to avoid any clashes and duplicate requests)
3. And last but not the least instead of Inter-Thread Communication Plugin you can just use JMeter Properties for passing the data across Thread Groups like it's described in [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables)